# How to change array to be object and get the data using with ajax json?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

The following coding is the out come of a php page show:

```
    user_list.php:
    $myarray=array();

    $myjson = json_encode($myarray);
    echo $myuser->searchUser($myjson);
```

---

and the result of html is:

```
    [{"userID":"1","username":"\u9ec3\u9ec3\u9ec3",
      "sex":"F","password":"1bbd886460827015e5d605ed44252251",
      "emails":"test@test.com","regdate":"2015-11-03 00:00:00",
      "dob":"1994-11-02","educationID":"6","positionID":"1",
      "home":"12341234","mobile":"21800000",
      "address":"AC2 5\F Rm5501","grade":"Y1",
      "status":"0","office_tel":"41234123",
      "inviter":null,"inviter_relation":null,"believe":"0",
      "remark":null}]
```

At I know, here is a array not an object. So how i can get those data in other page like this?

```
   $(".edituser").click(function () {
        var user = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax({
                  url:"user_list.php",
                  data:"userID="+user,
                  type : "POST",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success:function(data){  
                  **console.log(data);**
                  },
                  error:function(xhr){
                    alert('Ajax request fail');
                  }
                  });
    });
```

How get i get the data in ajax? thx

Comment: it's an array because it starts with [ ]... you can access like data[0].userID or data[0].emails etc.

Answer (score 1):

To get `userID` value, you can use:

```
var userID = data[0].userID;
```

or

```
var userID = data[0]['userID'];
```